# Formatting Seaborn Factorplot y-labels to percentages

Tags: matplotlib, format, seaborn

I'm trying to change the y-ticks to percentages in the following graph. The y variable is currently a mean of 0s and 1s. Is there a way to adjust the formatting to percentages in a factorplot?

```
plt.figure(figsize = (10, 7))
sns.factorplot(x="groups", y="has_invoice", hue = 'kind', 
    x_estimator=np.mean, data=df[df['app'] != 'other, other, web'], 
    order = ['< 2', '2-4', '4-6', '6-8', '8-10', '10-12', '12-14', '14- 
    16', '>16'], size=7, aspect=1)
plt.xlabel('#')
plt.title('')
plt.ylabel('Rate (#Has Invoices / #Total Count)', fontsize = 15)
```

[Can't upload an image yet but it should be attached here!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wd0Xl.png)

Comment: you need to use a `FuncFormatter` https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/custom_ticker1.html

Comment: You may use a `PercentFormatter` as seen in one of the answers to the duplicate. You would get the axes `ax` mentionned in that answer via `grid = sns.factorplot(...); ax = grid.axes[0,0]`.

Comment: I tried formatting according to the PercentFormatter and FunctFormatter and it's telling me that 'FacetGrid' object has no attribute 'yaxis'.